# "Game Center" iTunes Connect's developer guide left out one critical piece of information about editing "title" of leaderboards

Tags: app-store-connect, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

iTunes Connect's developer guide left out one critical piece of information about editing titles of Game Center leaderboards after your app is live on the Apple Store

they listed out, in a chart, every single variable that is and is not editable on a leaderboard, except the "title" for the leaderboard.

can someone who has a live app with game center running,  go into itunes Connect,  and see if you can edit the leaderboard titles? (not the leader board reference name)....  the titles? (listed as just "name" in itunes connect)

(it is important that I know for sure,  if you know for sure please let me know)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well,  i'm surprised no one wanted to answer this,  but for other's future use i did find out the answer, and yes you can edit the title name of a leader board..  which was good news in my case.